# WPF PropertyChanged code error: cannot implement 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

i have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Bix
{
    public class SettingsDataObject
    {
        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value == 0 ? Db.GetNextSettingsId() : value; }
        }
        private string adminEmail; public string AdminEmail { 
            get { return adminEmail; } 
            set { adminEmail = value; } 
        }
        private int state; public int State { get { return state; } set { state = value == 0 ? 1 : value; } }

        public object[] GetArray()
        {
            return new object[] { id, adminEmail, state };
        }

        public SettingsDataObject()
        {

        }
    }

    public class SettingsUIObjects : ObservableCollection<SettingsUIObject>,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected override void InsertItem(int index, SettingsUIObject item)
        {
            base.InsertItem(index, item);

            // handle any EndEdit events relating to this item
            item.ItemEndEdit += new SettingsUIObject.ItemEndEditEventHandler(ItemEndEditHandler);
            item.PropertyChanged += new SettingsUIObject.PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChanged);
        }

        public void ItemEndEditHandler(IEditableObject sender)
        {
            // simply forward any EndEdit events
            if (ItemEndEdit != null)
            {
                ItemEndEdit(sender);
            }
        }

        public event SettingsUIObject.ItemEndEditEventHandler ItemEndEdit;
        public event SettingsUIObject.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class SettingsDataProvider
    {
        private DataAccessLayer dl;

        public SettingsDataProvider()
        {
            dl = new DataAccessLayer();
        }

        public SettingsUIObjects GetSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                SettingsUIObjects objs = new SettingsUIObjects();

                List<SettingsDataObject> objDataObjects = dl.GetSettings();
                foreach (SettingsDataObject obj in objDataObjects)
                {
                    objs.Add(new SettingsUIObject(obj));
                }

                objs.ItemEndEdit += new SettingsUIObject.ItemEndEditEventHandler(SettingsItemEndEdit);
                objs.CollectionChanged += new
                  NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(SettingsCollectionChanged);
                objs.PropertyChanged += new SettingsUIObject.PropertyChangedEventHandler(SettingsPropertyChanged);
                return objs;
            }
            catch (Exception) { return new SettingsUIObjects(); }
        }

        void SettingsItemEndEdit(IEditableObject sender)
        {
            SettingsUIObject obj = sender as SettingsUIObject;

            // use the data access layer to update the wrapped data object
            dl.UpdateSettings(obj.GetDataObject());
        }

        void SettingsPropertyChanged(INotifyPropertyChanged sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SettingsUIObject obj = sender as SettingsUIObject;

            // use the data access layer to update the wrapped data object
            dl.UpdateSettings(obj.GetDataObject());
        }

        void SettingsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    SettingsUIObject obj = item as SettingsUIObject;

                    // use the data access layer to delete the wrapped data object
                    dl.DeleteSettings(obj.GetDataObject());
                }
            }
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    SettingsUIObject obj = item as SettingsUIObject;

                    // use the data access layer to delete the wrapped data object
                    dl.UpdateSettings(obj.GetDataObject());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SettingsUIObject : IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private SettingsDataObject obj;
        public SettingsUIObject(SettingsDataObject o)
        {
            obj = o;
        }

        public SettingsDataObject GetDataObject()
        {
            return obj;
        }

        public int Id { get { return obj.Id; } set { obj.Id = value; } }
        public string AdminEmail { 
            get { return obj.AdminEmail; } 
            set { obj.AdminEmail = value; } 
        }

        public delegate void ItemEndEditEventHandler(IEditableObject sender);

        public event ItemEndEditEventHandler ItemEndEdit;

        #region IEditableObject Members

        public void BeginEdit() { }

        public void CancelEdit() { }

        public void EndEdit()
        {
            if (ItemEndEdit != null)
            {
                ItemEndEdit(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(INotifyPropertyChanged sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and i keep getting the compile error:

'Bix.SettingsUIObject' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'. 'Bix.SettingsUIObject.PropertyChanged' cannot implement 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler'

can anyone tell me why?

thanks

Orson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(INotifyPropertyChanged sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Your code redeclares a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` delegate, which hides the one declared in `System.ComponentModel`. So your event is of type `SettingsUIObject.PropertyChangedEventHandler`, not `System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler`. Since the type doesn't match the one declared in `INotifyPropertyChanged`, your `PropertyChanged` event doesn't a valid implementation of the interface.

Just remove your `PropertyChangedEventHandler` delegate and it should work fine.